# best way to model java object with multiple datatypes

Tags: java, memory, object, subclass

What is the most memory efficient way to model a java object that will have multiple possible datatypes:
For example

```
public class Cell{

   short type

   int _int
   double _double
   String _string
}
```

Then instantiate this object and when setting the type set the appropriate value while leaving all others null. (I suspect this will take memory even if null except for String?)

Or,

```
public class Cell
{

   short type
}
public class StringCell extends Cell
{
   String _string

}
```

Where each type is a subclass of some common class that has only the appropriate datatype.
(I suspect there will be some memory over head associated with subclasses)

Comment: What do you plan on doing with the fields after they have been set (or set to null)?  Inheritance sounds like what you want.  Cell will have some common behaviour across all types?  But then you will have some special behaviour depending on the type of the cell?

Comment: yes there will be common stuff to all cells and cell specific work as well.

Comment: Out of curiosity, are you writing an interpreter?

Comment: no think excel like implementation where cells need to be stored, cells like numeric, string, boolean, date values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a classic problem for [generics](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/gentypes.html) since you say "setting the type set the appropriate value while leaving all others null."

```
public class Cell<T> {
    T value;
}
```

Then you can have...

```
Cell<String>  stringCell   = ...
Cell<Integer> integerCell  = ...
```

If Cell implemented a good interface you could even have a well defined collection of heterogeneous typed Cells.

Comment: So you're saying public class Cell<T> {

    private T t;


}
?

Comment: Though this is probably a good way to model this, it isn't necessarily "memory efficient", which was the very first sentence of the question. Storing a primitive int in an Integer is not efficient. Even more so in a 64-bit JVM.

Comment: But then I have no control over what is passed in the class as a generic. Somebody could say Cell<SomeFancyObject> not just the primitives I want to limit to

Comment: There are settings to reduce the pointer reference size in 64 bit JVMs. This is still far smaller then taking up N bytes for primitives if all but one is going to be null.

Comment: Even with a 32 bit reference, Integer will always take up more space than a primitive int. If his cells primarily hold primitives, which he has said he wants to limit to, then suggesting moving towards wrapper classes is not efficient memory wise.

Comment: @che: that's typically a good thing though there are ways around that. For one define an interface you are willing to accept and use the <T extends interface-i-approve-of> construct.

Comment: A better idea (for efficiency) is to have the storage for the data in its basic type, but then use generics to enforce returning it in its generic type, wrapped up. There's still the issue of creating the objects, but the objects might not enter the tenured or permanent generation since you're using them for a short period of time. Hope that makes sense.

Comment: @rfreak: I'm not going to argue this anymore. Try it and see which is better. For all we know the memory overhead might be acceptable.

Comment: -1 - You don't have to argue anymore. Check your facts. Null references still take up space. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1444242 Non-null references cost even more. It's not memory efficient, which was the OP question. I don't need to put it into a profiler to "try it." These are simple Java facts.

Answer (score 0):

You are over thinking this. If you really need this then stick to primitives and also look if [Flyweight pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flyweight_pattern) can help.

Comment: Yes the Flyweight could help for shared Strings but that is just another optimization.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to work with int, long, float, and double primitives, the most efficient way IS to use the primitive themselves. However, setting them to null is impossible. Simply declaring them in the class will take up space.

Going with a subclass approach may work, but that begs the question, what value is the base class? I'd lean towards an Interface, with different implementations per primitive type. That way you have no inheritance overhead (though I doubt there is any) AND you only have the primitive you need.

I still question what you would put on that Interface though. Possibly some sort of a Render method?